# Serializing classes created with Singleton pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, serialization

In my program, All of my classes are using singleton pattern, except the one which is the main window. Because of that, all the singleton connections are maintained by one singleton class, "Manager". GUI access methods in other classes via the public methods in this class.

Now, I am trying to save my work (serialize) and I am always getting the error "Form1 not serialized". That is the GUI class. So, I marked that as serialized, knowing that is not a good idea. Now it is saying "System.windows.forms not serialized". Why is this? Is it unable to serialize a class with singleton access? Please help.

Note: I am a Java developer learning "Head First C#". This is my first attempt to make one of their "Lab" problems in my own preferred way.

Comment: Please include relevant code so that I might be able to provide a contextually appropriate answer.

Comment: How are you serializing? What is the full exception?

Comment: In general, you should be serializing *data*. UI components should be constructed anew upon each run, and then the data they were displaying deserialized and shown. If for some reason your data class refers to the form that is showing it, then you should be marking that field as *non*-serializable, not attempting to serialize it.

Comment: Everything @dlev says, basically. Serialising UI controls is a ***really really** bad idea. Store data.

Comment: *All* your classes are singletons? That sounds like a maintenance and testing nightmare.

Comment: Yes, it is a game. All those classes are maintaining a part of the game's state. For an example, one is maintaining the score, another one maintains  ranks, another one maintains belts like wise. All deals with the GUI to update score, ranks and belts. So, only one instance should be there right? You can imagine what will happen if more than one instance got generated! The GUI will end up with wrong results !! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing code it's hard to know what is wrong.  Principally one can serialize a form (I just did so using the sample `Test<T>(T obj)` method [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675198.aspx) which uses [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx)).

**Having said that...** it is unwise to serialize the form itself in order to save the form state.  Instead, you should keep your data in a separate class (commonly referred to as a Model class, see [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) and serialize the data instead.  Use data binding or the MVC pattern to connect your form (the view) to the data (the model).

If this is WinForms (as I presume), one can use MVC with WinForms

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406/looking-for-a-mvc-sample-for-winforms

For information about data binding with WinForms, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx

Comment: So... why are you getting an error about Form1 not being serialized?  Post some code...

Comment: But wait! One data class is generating MessageBox.Show() !!!! This class MUST be serialized. Do I have to remove that line of code?

Comment: If data classes are showing a message box, it's really because they desire some form of interaction.  I would change that to have the data class raise an event, and have the form subscribe to that event and have the form show the MessageBox.  Great guide on events here: http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html

Comment: That's sounds better. I think this might be the issue. I will reply after checking this out. :)